# Converting Prefix to Postfix expression in python

Tags: python, binary-tree

I am a beginner and been learning python for a couple of months now.

Trying to work out the subject problem using Tree method but not successful. However, I could not determine which is not working.

```
    class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def prefix_to_postfix(expression):
        stack = []

        for i in range(len(expression) - 1, -1, -1):
            if expression[i].isdigit():
                # If the current character is a digit, create a node
                # with the digit and push it to the stack
                node = Node(expression[i])
                stack.append(node)
            else:
                # If the current character is an operator, pop two nodes
                # from the stack and create a new node with the operator
                # as the root, and the popped nodes as its left and right children
                left = stack.pop()
                right = stack.pop()
                node = Node(expression[i])
                node.left = left
                node.right = right
                stack.append(node)

        root = stack.pop()
        postfix = ''
        
    def postorder(root):
        if root:
            postorder(root.left)
            postorder(root.right)
            postfix += root.data
        return postfix
```

```
prefix_to_postfix("+*AB-CD")
output: AB*+CD-
expected AB*CD-+
```

Appreciated if anyone can point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You write that for `print(prefix_to_postfix("+*ABC"))` you get the wrong output, but it is not possible you get that output with the code you shared -- it produces errors.

Here are some issues:

- The indentation is wrong. `__init__` should be a method of the `Node` class, while the other two functions are to be top-level functions.
- `postorder` references a name that it doesn't know about: `postfix`
- `postorder` is never called by `print(prefix_to_postfix("+*ABC"))`
- `isdigit()` is never true for this example input, so every character in your input would be considered an operator, and no operands would be recognised.
- `prefix_to_postfix` does not return anything, so `print(prefix_to_postfix("+*ABC"))` could never print anything other than `None`
- `prefix_to_postfix` sets `postfix` to the empty string and then never does anything with it.
- `postorder` is called recursively, but the value returned by that recursive call is ignored.

Here is a correction of your program:

```
class Node:  # indentation fixed
    def __init__(self, data): 
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def prefix_to_postfix(expression):  # indentation fixed
    stack = []

    for i in range(len(expression) - 1, -1, -1):
        if expression[i].isalnum():  # consider letters as operands too
            node = Node(expression[i])
            stack.append(node)
        else:
            left = stack.pop()
            right = stack.pop()
            node = Node(expression[i])
            node.left = left
            node.right = right
            stack.append(node)

    root = stack.pop()
    return postorder(root)   # call the other function and return its result
    
def postorder(root):
    postfix = ''  # define this name here
    if root:
        postfix += postorder(root.left)  # don't ignore returned value
        postfix += postorder(root.right)
        postfix += root.data
    return postfix
```

With these fixes we can do:

```
print(prefix_to_postfix("+*AB-CD"))
```

And the output is:

```
AB*CD-+
```

Comment: Thanks trincot. I tried another prefix expression like: "/ + 1 9 - 5 6" with spaces in between which gives an IndexError: pop from empty list. The output should be "1 9 + 5 6 - /". Any direction on how to fix this?

Comment: What should happen if there are sometimes spaces, and sometimes not, like what is the expected output for `"/ +1 9- 5 6"`? Where to put the spaces?

Comment: @trincot there's nothing stopping you from removing any spaces so that the format is always the same

Comment: @hillybob991, sure, but my question was about the expected output, not the input. They have not come back, so I guess they lost interest.